# Cannot see AAD group in Blazor server app

Tags: c#, azure, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor Server application i have added Azure Ad authentication.

In program.cs file i have this code.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Users", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context => context.User.HasClaim(c =>
        {
            return c.Type == "groups" && c.Value.Contains(builder.Configuration["groups:Users"]);
        }));
    });

    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context => context.User.HasClaim(c =>
        {
            return c.Type == "groups" && c.Value.Contains(builder.Configuration["groups:Admin"]);
        }));
    });
});
```

And in my appsettings I have this

```
  "groups": {
    "Users": "2bxxxxx6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-be68xxxxxb21",
    "Admin": "61xxxxx9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-270bxxxxx314"
  }
```

And in my code I have this

```
    var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    User = authState.User;
    IsUserInEventumUsersGroup = User.HasClaim(c =>
        c.Type == "groups" 
        && c.Value.Contains(Configuration["groups:Admin"])
    );
```

The last code gives me false everytime.
If I try with the groups:Users I get true.
In Azure AD my user is a member of both groups.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I works now without me changing anything.
Properly just had to wait for Azure to be ready.